# Add a new tab for a UITabBarController to another storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I have a different storyboard for a tab in my UITabViewController. How to I connect it?

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize view controller from any storyboard (do not forget to initialize storyboard first) using:

`- (id)instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;`

And set required view controllers using UITabBarController method

`- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated;`

Comment: I have a few connected in storyboard already. I just want the fourth connected programmatically!!